# Google Maps Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, php

I try to make a menu bar with icons which show the same icons in the map when clicked, for example hotels or bars.

I made a form with radio buttons for choose and click submit. This goes to PHP, connects to PostgreSQL, executes the query, and returns a result. It is not good solution though, because I want the user click on a icon to dynamically show the icons in map without any need to click on a submit button.

Is it possible, does an example exist?

I try to make it with jQueries and AJAX
i make a jQuery which if i click show a alert massage i try to put the AJAX conection to return the JSONarray but is not make anythin
This is a snapshot of php and javascript code.
PHP
conectin database
make fetch

```
insert  data in array with this line of code

if($type=="warning"){

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $row_array['gid'] = $row['gid'];
        $row_array['cause'] = $row['cause'];
        $row_array['duration'] = $row['duration'];
        $row_array['image'] = $row['image'];
            $row_array['km'] = $row['km'];
        $row_array['coords'] = json_decode($row['geom'], true);

        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
}
   echo $json_response;
```

JavaScript 
code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".warning").click(function(event){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'php/ajax-follow.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {'type': 'warning'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            imgAr = JSON.parse($json_response);
                            alert(imgAr);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                            console.log(xhr);
                            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could issue a [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to your PHP service. In Javascript, add an event listener to your radio buttons that [listens for change events](http://api.jquery.com/change/). In the listener, issue the AJAX request to your PHP service. Handle the response of the PHP server in the AJAX callback and update your map.

Comment: The AJAX request i dont understand how i make it , for every image have a link and make a listens but AJAX who is return the values from php ?